# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I got this error from some devices with Android 4.4 like Galaxy Tab3 8.0 (lt01wifi) if you have this tab,please reply.
The app works just fine on the rest of the devices.
Please help me! i'm having a lot of bad ratings..

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{aladin888.dessin/aladin888.dessin.Splash}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2208)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.Activity.setRequestedOrientation(Activity.java:4453)
```

And i can't figure out where's the issue. everything seems to be correct (to me) in my manifest.The activity in question is registred as you can see:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="aladin888.dessin"
    android:versionCode="10"
    android:versionName="1.9.0" >

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>    


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="aladin888.dessin.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="aladin888.dessin.EasyPaint"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
   </application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you for your help Dawnkeeper! but i'm still having the same issue, and i'm getting a lot bad ratings 
Any more ideas will be very appreciated!!

Comment: Am I seeing it right, that your package name is `aladin888.dessin` and your activity is called `Splash` ? Because it looks to me, Android is looking for an activity in `aladin888.dessin/aladin888.dessin.splash`

Comment: Say, what orientation are you requesting ?
And what version of android is running on the system you are testing with?

Comment: I get these errors reports from app users at google play.. i guess they run on 4.4.x The orientation is forced to portrait Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing the package in the name

```
 android:name="aladin888.dessin.Splash"
```

should be

```
android:name=".Splash"
```

**edit**

As we found out this isn't really the problem. Another hint is this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.Activity.setRequestedOrientation(Activity.java:4453)
```

I searched for a while, but could not find a android version that has this method at the given line. What I found out is that method has not changed in a while:

```
 public void setRequestedOrientation(int requestedOrientation) {
       if (mParent == null) {
           try {
                ActivityManagerNative.getDefault().setRequestedOrientation(
                        mToken, requestedOrientation);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // Empty
            }
        } else {
            mParent.setRequestedOrientation(requestedOrientation);
        }
    }
```

The only chance I see for this failing is when  the ActivityManagerNative.getDefault() returns null. I couldn't find anything helpful for this issue.

Comment: thanks! it's was without package name, but i changed it to aladin888.dessin.Splash trying to solve the issue, but both ways didn't solve the issue in the devices i mentionned above.

Comment: Yes noticed this too. Could you try to adding this to your activity `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`? The last line of your log seems to indicate an error with finding the default orientation.

Comment: Good idea! I will set that now. I really appreciate your attention. Also i guess it's because i didn't set targetSdkVersion, the app is installed on newer android version than the one i compiled with the 4.4.1

Comment: I'm still having the same trouble with S3 :(